# JQuery: Visual studio, error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

Tags: asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2008

Trying to include ThickBox (from http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) in an ASP.NET application.

Visual Studio is failing when I try to run the application with the error:
js\ThickBox\jquery-1.2.6.min.js(11): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

Using Visual Studio 2008
and jquery 1.2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe is because of the conflict between jQuery $ and the one defined by the asp.net script library.

You can call jQuery.noConflict() then use jQuery instead of $. For example instead of $("#test") you will call jQuery("#test").

See http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict for more info.

Comment: Never knew about that. 

Thanks for the answer, I fixed it by removing the runat="server" attribute of the link. Was hoping to use that to resolve the path from the master page...

Answer (score 16):

CS1056 is obviously a C# compiler error. This kind of thing happens when you put runat="server" in a client script include tag (Visual Studio attempts to compile your .js file as if it was C#). Just remove the runat="server" attribute and try again.

Comment: I had some other compiler error, which was actually coming from the js file itself. Your advice helped me :)

Comment: +1 Great answer, i was fighting with this error for last 3 hours. But never expected that this can be a reason

Comment: I could do that, but then an url in the format "~/foo/bar.js" will not resolve.

Comment: Check this answer (and others in the thread) on how to resolve server paths to client scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1666837/47602

Answer (score 0):

when ever we put runat="server" within script tag ,this error wil occur.

for eg:

```
script  type="text/javascript" id="kk" runat="server" src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"
```

so just remove the runat=server then this error wont come.

Answer (score 0):

This occured for me when I was writing jQuery code in the `onClick` event of my asp server control.

`onClientClick` was surely a better option for this purpose ;)