# How to include Javascript file in Asp.Net page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, master-pages

I want to do some client side validation using javascript in ASP.NET page.

I tried using

`<script src="../../../JS/Registration.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" />`

but its not working.
Please help.

Comment: Can you explain 'it is not working'?

Comment: FYI `<script>` tags aren't self closing. You should be using `</script>`.

Comment: Note that when you drag/drop jquery file into master page, the file name will be incorrect if you are in subfolder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the file is not in the path specified. '../../../' will move 3 step up to the directory in which the page is located and look for the js file in a folder named JS.

Also the ***language*** attribute is Deprecated.

See [Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> ### [18.2.1 The SCRIPT element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)
>
> `language` = ***[cdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata)*** [[**CI**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#case-insensitive)]
>
> **[Deprecated.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated)** This attribute specifies
>   the scripting language of the contents
>   of this element. Its value is an
>   identifier for the language, but since
>   these identifiers are not standard,
>   this attribute has been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated) in
>   favor of type.

***Edit***

Try changing

```
<script src="../../../JS/Registration.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" />
```

to

```
<script src="../../../JS/Registration.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am sure, file is present at this path.

Comment: Maybe you're using master pages or something else and not quite sure where the files are launched.
Simply open the file in the browser, press "view source" and use the JS path in the URL to see if it opens. Your syntax is (more or less) correct.

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is also not necessary here

Answer (score 49):

If your page is deeply pathed or might move around and your JS script is at "~/JS/Registration.js" of your web folder, you can try the following:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/JS/Registration.js") %>' 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 24):

add like

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="Registration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

OR can add in code behind.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Registration", ResolveUrl("~/js/Registration.js"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are using **MasterPage** so within your master page you should have

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

And within any of your pages based on that **MasterPage** add this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="js/yourscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Great answer if you are using master pages.

Answer (score 4):

`ScriptManager` control can also be used to reference javascript files. One catch is that the `ScriptManager` control needs to be place inside the `form` tag. I myself prefer `ScriptManager` control and generally place it just above the closing `form` tag.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/yourscript.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is happening. Then change the path accordingly. You will probably find you get a 404 error and the path is wrong.