# Local deployment of ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, installation, setup-project

I was tasked to automate a small tool using `Web Forms`.

We have figured out that deploying it into a web server would **not** be worth it since the application is only comprised of **one** `.aspx` page, playing around with `UpdatePanels`, exporting the required `PDF` with the consolidated numbers, etc. **No** database was involved. The calculations are done on `postbacks`.

Is it possible to create an **installer** instead? Like the idea of being able to use the app after they run the installer that they received?

Or only `deploying locally` is the **ONLY** work around on hosting it on a `web server`?

My team won't be using the automated tool. We automated the task so that the requestor could generate the results on their own using the tool. It is also my **first time** deploying a project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can the automation not be done through a simple Windows forms/Console app?

Comment: It reads several `csv` files and generates results `pdf`. But I'm not sure..

Comment: Unless you need a GUI for some easy user inputs, you don't need to use ASP.NET at all. It can be much easier and efficient using a simple console app which you can schedule as a task to run automatically.

Comment: I'm done coding everything though. I'm not knowledgeable about deployment and is seeking guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Please check if it helps- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b07128/deploy-Asp-Net-website-on-iis-in-our-local-machine/

Comment: Hi @SouvikGhosh, I followed all the steps and was **able** to access it on my machine. However, my goal is for my colleagues to access it also. They got an `HTTP 404` error instead when I gave them the link. Kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: you just have to access it with the computer name. refer these- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896534/accessing-a-local-website-from-another-computer-inside-the-local-network-in-iis and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826803/How-to-Access-the-Site-using-Domain-Name-Instead-o

Comment: @SouvikGhosh and also, I noticed that the `js` files in the Script catch an error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)` Any thoughts on that also? :)

Comment: That is because the reference paths you haven't configured properly. Please check these- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735684/asp-net-path-to-use-to-reference-css-and-js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666797/how-to-include-javascript-file-in-asp-net-page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509508/how-to-properly-reference-a-javascript-file-in-an-asp-net-project

Comment: I have resolved the error on the `js` scripts. The error on the **fonts** (`woff`, `woff2`, etc) remain. I think my colleagues can't connect due to our Symantec firewall.